# Dynamic 2D array, checking the size of the given "X"

Tags: c, arrays

Well, the title is phrased badly so I will try to explain my problem here in detail.

I've an 2D array,for example: `3x4` `{{22, 1, 0 , 2}, {6,5,1,33} , {13,42,0,9}}`

This 2D array was randomly chosen from  `rand() % 100 + 1` function.

Task: given an input from user, I want to check the size of that number.

Let's say the number is represented by `x` if the input is 3, then `x = 3`

And we can see that when `x = 3` , the output will be `2`.

If you didn't understand that, I'll show some more inputs:

If `x = 1`, output 0, if `x = 2`, output 1, if `x = 4`, output 5,if `x = 7`, output is 13, if `x = 11`, output -1 (because there isn't).

So, I'm kinda new to programming and I'm not sure how to solve it. but what I have in mind is:

Step 1: Get input from user and store it in x.

Step 2: Sort the 2D array ( Taking 2d array in 1d array, then bubble sorting)

Step 3: Check somehow that arr[x-1] is valid. and if it is, output it.

What do you guys think? Here's my code just for printing a randomized 2D array. any help would be highly appreciated!

**Edit:** Here's the updated code, now I only need to find x.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h>  



int main(void)
{
    int m, n = 0, i, j, k = 0, temp; //m = rows, n = cols
    int **arr; //Dynamic alloc. for 2D mat.
    int *oneDArr;
    srand(time(NULL)); //rand new values

    printf("Please enter a number:(m) \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Please enter a number:(n) \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    arr = (int**)malloc(m * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    printf("The matrix is %d x %d \n", m, n);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    oneDArr = (int*)malloc((m*n) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            oneDArr[k] = arr[i][j];
            printf("%d ", oneDArr[k]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = k - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (j = 0;j < i; j++) {
            if (oneDArr[j] > oneDArr[j + 1])
            {
                temp = oneDArr[j];
                oneDArr[j] = oneDArr[j + 1];
                oneDArr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < m*n;i++)
        printf("%d ", oneDArr[i]);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So What's the matter?  I thinks duplicate elements need to be processed to remove.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Well, the first problem is, it does not print the values of the 2D array.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Update2: I got it to print 2D array and copy it to 1D array, now I need to study bubble sorting and I'm coming back with an update! sorry for my newbness :(

Comment: 1)  I think it has been printed. 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I just studied bubble sort and updated my code. now everything I've got left to do is to find that x.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm checking your code now, although I really want finish my code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){
    int m, n, i, j, k, x; //m = rows, n = cols
    int **arr; //Dynamic alloc. for 2D mat.
    int *oneDArr;
    int work[101] = {0};//for sort
    srand(time(NULL)); //rand new values

    printf("Please enter a number:(m) \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Please enter a number:(n) \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    arr = (int**)malloc(m * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    printf("The matrix is %d x %d \n", m, n);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;//1-100, 0 is not included.
            printf("%3d ", arr[i][j]);
            ++work[ arr[i][j] ];//Existence flag
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    oneDArr = (int*)malloc((m*n) * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 1, k = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        if(work[i])
            oneDArr[k++] = i;
    }
    printf("input X :\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if(x > k)
        puts("-1");
    else
        printf("%d\n", oneDArr[x-1]);
    //deallocation
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant and I suck in programming! I make everything looks complicated with my code and you make it look so simple like you are coding for some years in C now. I hope I pass the test though. Thank you.